# Fails to generate image using openai

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I am trying to take a text from discord user and then generating an image of that. I made a code for that but openai shows 400 error.

Error:

```js
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/BACKUP/s/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/BACKUP/s/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/BACKUP/s/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Code:

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai')
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: 'sk-aqe0eRo77gOnnSBR2n7'
})
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

let text = interaction.options.getString(`text`)
const response = await openai.createImage({
  prompt: text,
  n: 1,
  size: '1024x1024',
});
let imageUrl = response.data.data[0].url;
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('Generated Image')
  .setImage(imageUrl);
interaction.editReply(embed)
  .catch(error => {
    interaction.editReply('Failed to generate image');
  });
```

I have taking prompt as text from discord slash command options

I don't know what is this error for please help me fix this.

Comment: Looks like your api key is shorter than expected. Can you double check it?

Comment: Key is correct I original code I removed some part of key to hide it from public

Comment: I think it's a problem with your api key. Can you try to re generate a new one and try again?

Comment: You should never post an api key here. Revoke your exposed API key and generate a new one.

Comment: @EliasSoares Let me clear the api key shown in code is fake.

Comment: @devpolo Tried with other key too but same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a issue with openAI which is now resolved it will work now.